# filter blacklist domains from file

Tags: bash, awk

I have two files

first file blacklist.txt contains

```
test.example.com
*.test.example.com
```

second file subdomains.txt contains

```
test.example.com
123.test.example.com
abc-test.example.com
www.example.com
```

Expected results file conatains

```
abc-test.example.com
www.example.com
```

which is filter all subdomains listed in blacklist file from subdomains.txt
AND it check for regex in the same time if there is `*.` then will remove all subdomains too as shown in expected results .

during my search i find the following command using awk but dos not work in case there is `*` in file blacklist.txt
`awk 'NR == FNR { list[tolower($0)]=1; next } { if (! list[tolower($0)]) print }' blacklist.txt  subdomains.txt`

but when it contains only domain it will filter out

i have tried comm command too but it look like dos not handle regex

Comment: Your blacklist uses shell wildcard patterns, not regular expressions, btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you process the blacklist with sed to turn it into a regex list, you can do it with:

```sh
sed 's/\./\\./g;s/\*/.*/g' blacklist.txt |
grep -vixf - subdomains.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

If you modify the blacklist regexps a bit:

```
test\.example\.com
.*\.test\.example\.com
```

you could:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {
    a[$0];next
}
{
    for(i in a)
        if(match($0,"^" i "$"))
            next
    print
}' blacklist subdomains
```

Output:

```
abc-test.example.com
www.example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

A pure `bash` version that doesn't require any pre-processing of the blacklist patterns:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

readarray -t blacklist < blacklist.txt
while read -r domain; do
    match=0
    for pat in "${blacklist[@]}"; do
        if [[ $domain == $pat ]]; then
            match=1
            break
        fi
    done
    [[ $match -eq 0 ]] && printf "%s\n" "$domain"
done < subdomains.txt
```

And to throw it in, a `tcl` version that should be much more efficient than the above script on large files:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

# Takes two arguments; the blacklist file and the domain file
# e.g.,
# ./domainfilter blacklist.txt subdomains.txt > results.txt

proc ggrep {blacklist domainfile} {
    set f [open $domainfile]
    set domains [split [read -nonewline $f] \n]
    close $f
    set f [open $blacklist]
    while {[gets $f pattern] >= 0} {
        set domains [lsearch -inline -all -not -glob $domains $pattern]
    }
    close $f
    puts [join $domains \n]
}
ggrep [lindex $argv 0] [lindex $argv 1]
```

Also a more efficient `zsh` version, if that shell is an option:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

declare -A blacklist
while read -r pattern; do
    blacklist[$pattern]=1
done < blacklist.txt

while read -r domain; do
    # Treat the array keys as glob patterns matched against index
    [[ -z ${blacklist[(k)$domain]} ]] && printf "%s\n" "$domain"
done < subdomains.txt
```

Comment: Turning the blacklist into an extended globbing pattern might be more efficient for Bash: `readarray -t blacklist < blacklist.txt; IFS='|'; printf -v pattern '!(%s)' "${blacklist[*]}"; shopt -s extglob; while read -r domain; do [[ $domain == $pattern ]] && printf "%s\n" "$domain";done < subdomains.txt`

Comment: @LéaGris I swear I remember seeing something in the bash documentation suggesting not to use extended globs with lots of alternation because it's dog slow, but I can't find it again. EDIT: Ah-ha! All the way at the bottom of https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html

Comment: (And even if it is slow, if it's slower than a nested shell loop or not would have to be benchmarked...)

Comment: Now I kind of want to write a version of grep that uses globs instead of REs.

Comment: you can certainly abuse a filesystem like /dev/shm